# Creating a collapsing left nav style column

Tags: jquery, css, twitter-bootstrap, menu

I'm trying to figure out how to combine this type of [sidebar navigation](http://jsfiddle.net/kylebellamy/YJB4q/296/) with the layout I have in my [JSfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/kylebellamy/yc1aanoj/1/).

In the first example, the sidebar collapses to the main icons and I see how that is done but it is using the Nav tag which is not ideal as it's physical space not respected by the content of the page. It slides under the content of the page instead of pushing it over to resize.

Ideally, I'd like that nav to be placed in a column that keeps it's own space and top aligned with the other rows like in the second JSfiddle, resizing the rows and columns to the right accordingly depending on the open or collapsed state of it.

Or is there a much simpler way to achieve this leaving out the Nav tag altogether?

Sidebar Functions I like:

Html:

```
<body>

<div class="row">
<div class="col-md-12" style="height:60px;">
Header Area

</div>
</div>

<div class="row">

<div class="col-md-1">
    <nav class='sidebar sidebar-menu-collapsed'> <a href='#' id='justify-icon'>
        <span class='glyphicon glyphicon-align-justify'></span>
      </a>

        <ul class='level1'>
            <li class='active'> <a class='expandable' href='#' title='Dashboard'>
            <span class='glyphicon glyphicon-home collapsed-element'></span>
            <span class='expanded-element'>Dashboard</span>
          </a>

                <ul class='level2'>
                    <li> <a href='#' title='Traffic'>Traffic</a>

                    </li>
                    <li> <a href='#' title='Conversion rate'>Conversion rate</a>

                    </li>
                    <li> <a href='#' title='Purchases'>Purchases</a>

                    </li>
                </ul>
            </li>
            <li> <a class='expandable' href='#' title='APIs'>
            <span class='glyphicon glyphicon-wrench collapsed-element'></span>
            <span class='expanded-element'>APIs</span>
          </a>

            </li>
            <li> <a class='expandable' href='#' title='Settings'>
            <span class='glyphicon glyphicon-cog collapsed-element'></span>
            <span class='expanded-element'>Settings</span>
          </a>

            </li>
            <li> <a class='expandable' href='#' title='Account'>
            <span class='glyphicon glyphicon-user collapsed-element'></span>
            <span class='expanded-element'>Account</span>
          </a>

            </li>
        </ul> <a href='#' id='logout-icon' title='Logout'>
        <span class='glyphicon glyphicon-off'></span>
      </a>

    </nav>
    </div>

    <div class="col-md-11">
    <p>
    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.
    </p>
    <p>
    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.
    </p>
    </div>
    </div>
</body>
```

Javascript:

```
(function () {
    $(function () {
        var SideBAR;
        SideBAR = (function () {
            function SideBAR() {}

            SideBAR.prototype.expandMyMenu = function () {
                return $("nav.sidebar").removeClass("sidebar-menu-collapsed").addClass("sidebar-menu-expanded");
            };

            SideBAR.prototype.collapseMyMenu = function () {
                return $("nav.sidebar").removeClass("sidebar-menu-expanded").addClass("sidebar-menu-collapsed");
            };

            SideBAR.prototype.showMenuTexts = function () {
                return $("nav.sidebar ul a span.expanded-element").show();
            };

            SideBAR.prototype.hideMenuTexts = function () {
                return $("nav.sidebar ul a span.expanded-element").hide();
            };

            SideBAR.prototype.showActiveSubMenu = function () {
                $("li.active ul.level2").show();
                return $("li.active a.expandable").css({
                    width: "100%"
                });
            };

            SideBAR.prototype.hideActiveSubMenu = function () {
                return $("li.active ul.level2").hide();
            };

            SideBAR.prototype.adjustPaddingOnExpand = function () {
                $("ul.level1 li a.expandable").css({
                    padding: "1px 4px 4px 0px"
                });
                return $("ul.level1 li.active a.expandable").css({
                    padding: "1px 4px 4px 4px"
                });
            };

            SideBAR.prototype.resetOriginalPaddingOnCollapse = function () {
                $("ul.nbs-level1 li a.expandable").css({
                    padding: "4px 4px 4px 0px"
                });
                return $("ul.level1 li.active a.expandable").css({
                    padding: "4px"
                });
            };

            SideBAR.prototype.ignite = function () {
                return (function (instance) {
                    return $("#justify-icon").click(function (e) {
                        if ($(this).parent("nav.sidebar").hasClass("sidebar-menu-collapsed")) {
                            instance.adjustPaddingOnExpand();
                            instance.expandMyMenu();
                            instance.showMenuTexts();
                            instance.showActiveSubMenu();
                            $(this).css({
                                color: "#000"
                            });
                        } else if ($(this).parent("nav.sidebar").hasClass("sidebar-menu-expanded")) {
                            instance.resetOriginalPaddingOnCollapse();
                            instance.collapseMyMenu();
                            instance.hideMenuTexts();
                            instance.hideActiveSubMenu();
                            $(this).css({
                                color: "#FFF"
                            });
                        }
                        return false;
                    });
                })(this);
            };

            return SideBAR;

        })();
        return (new SideBAR).ignite();
    });

}).call(this);
```

CSS-

```
@import url('http://getbootstrap.com/dist/css/bootstrap.css');
 @import url("//netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.0.0-rc2/css/bootstrap-glyphicons.css");
 body {
    background: none repeat scroll 0 0 white;
}
nav.sidebar-menu-collapsed {
    width: 44px;
}
nav.sidebar-menu-expanded {
    width: auto;
}
nav.sidebar {
    position: fixed;
    top: 0px;
    left: 0px;
    height: 100%;
    background: none repeat scroll 0 0 #0099ff;
    color: white;
    padding: 20px 10px;
}
nav.sidebar a#justify-icon {
    outline: 0;
    color: white;
    font-size: 24px;
    font-style: normal;
}
nav.sidebar a#logout-icon {
    outline: 0;
    color: white;
    font-size: 24px;
    font-style: normal;
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 10px;
    left: 10px;
}
nav.sidebar ul.level1 {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    margin-top: 60px;
}
nav.sidebar ul.level1 li {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    margin-top: 20px;
    list-style-type: none;
}
nav.sidebar ul.level1 li a.expandable {
    outline: 0;
    display: block;
    position: relative;
    width: 100%;
    height: 30px;
    color: white;
    text-decoration: none;
    text-align: left;
    padding: 4px 4px 4px 0px;
    font-size: 20px;
}
nav.sidebar ul.level1 li a.expandable:hover {
    color: #bbbbbb;
}
nav.sidebar ul.level1 li a.expandable span.expanded-element {
    display: none;
    font-size: 11px;
    position: relative;
    bottom: 5px;
}
nav.sidebar ul.level1 li.active {
    margin-left: -4px;
}
nav.sidebar ul.level1 li.active a.expandable {
    background: none repeat scroll 0 0 black;
    border-radius: 4px;
    color: white !important;
    width: 30px;
    padding: 4px;
}
nav.sidebar ul.level1 li.active a.expandable:hover {
    color: white !important;
}
nav.sidebar ul.level1 ul.level2 {
    margin: 20px 6px 20px 30px;
    padding: 0;
    display: none;
}
nav.sidebar ul.level1 ul.level2 li {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    margin-top: 10px;
    padding-bottom: 10px;
    list-style-type: none;
    border-bottom: solid white 1px;
}
nav.sidebar ul.level1 ul.level2 li:last-child {
    border-bottom: none;
}
nav.sidebar ul.level1 ul.level2 li a {
    text-decoration: none;
    outline: 0;
    color: white;
    text-decoration: none;
    font-size: 11px;
}
```

Desired Layout:

```
<div class="row" style="height:60px; margin-bottom:10px;">
    <div class="well">
        Header area
    </div>
</div>

<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-4">
        <div class="well">
            <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-menu-hamburger pull-right" ></span>
            <br/>
            <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-home"></span> &nbsp;&nbsp;Home
            <br/>
            <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-thumbs-up"></span> &nbsp;&nbsp;Thumbs Up
            <br/>
            <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-picture"></span> &nbsp;&nbsp;Picture
            <br/>
            <br/>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-8">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-12">
                <div class="well">2</div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-12">
                <div class="well">4</div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: So, let me try to understand one thing, you don't want it to go from absolute top to bottom, but rather, to fill the height of the "row" it's in?

Comment: Yes, that's what I was asking, somehow I didn't get that out. I can see from my one example it uses prototype as well which adds further complexity.

Answer (score 1):

So, something like this?

```js
(function () {
    $(function () {
        var SideBAR;
        SideBAR = (function () {
            function SideBAR() {}

            SideBAR.prototype.expandMyMenu = function () {
                return $(".sidebar").removeClass("sidebar-menu-collapsed").addClass("sidebar-menu-expanded");
            };

            SideBAR.prototype.collapseMyMenu = function () {
                return $(".sidebar").removeClass("sidebar-menu-expanded").addClass("sidebar-menu-collapsed");
            };

            SideBAR.prototype.showMenuTexts = function () {
                return $(".sidebar ul a span.expanded-element").show();
            };

            SideBAR.prototype.hideMenuTexts = function () {
                return $(".sidebar ul a span.expanded-element").hide();
            };

            SideBAR.prototype.showActiveSubMenu = function () {
                $("li.active ul.level2").show();
                return $("li.active a.expandable").css({
                    width: "100%"
                });
            };

            SideBAR.prototype.hideActiveSubMenu = function () {
                return $("li.active ul.level2").hide();
            };

            SideBAR.prototype.adjustPaddingOnExpand = function () {
                $("ul.level1 li a.expandable").css({
                    padding: "1px 4px 4px 0px"
                });
                return $("ul.level1 li.active a.expandable").css({
                    padding: "1px 4px 4px 4px"
                });
            };

            SideBAR.prototype.resetOriginalPaddingOnCollapse = function () {
                $("ul.nbs-level1 li a.expandable").css({
                    padding: "4px 4px 4px 0px"
                });
                return $("ul.level1 li.active a.expandable").css({
                    padding: "4px"
                });
            };

            SideBAR.prototype.ignite = function () {
                return (function (instance) {
                    return $("#justify-icon").click(function (e) {
                        if ($(this).parent(".sidebar").hasClass("sidebar-menu-collapsed")) {
                            instance.adjustPaddingOnExpand();
                            instance.expandMyMenu();
                            instance.showMenuTexts();
                            instance.showActiveSubMenu();
                            $(this).css({
                                color: "#000"
                            });
                        } else if ($(this).parent(".sidebar").hasClass("sidebar-menu-expanded")) {
                            instance.resetOriginalPaddingOnCollapse();
                            instance.collapseMyMenu();
                            instance.hideMenuTexts();
                            instance.hideActiveSubMenu();
                            $(this).css({
                                color: "#FFF"
                            });
                        }
                        return false;
                    });
                })(this);
            };

            return SideBAR;

        })();
        return (new SideBAR).ignite();
    });

}).call(this);
```

```css
@import url('http://getbootstrap.com/dist/css/bootstrap.css');
@import url("//netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.0.0-rc2/css/bootstrap-glyphicons.css");

body {
    background: none repeat scroll 0 0 white;
}

nav.sidebar-menu-collapsed {
    width: 44px;
}
nav.sidebar-menu-expanded {
    width: auto;
}
nav.sidebar {
    background: none repeat scroll 0 0 #0099ff;
    color: white;
    padding: 20px 10px;
}
nav.sidebar a#justify-icon {
    outline: 0;
    color: white;
    font-size: 24px;
    font-style: normal;
}
nav.sidebar a#logout-icon {
    outline: 0;
    color: white;
    font-size: 24px;
    font-style: normal;
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 10px;
    left: 10px;
}
nav.sidebar ul.level1 {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    margin-top: 60px;
}
nav.sidebar ul.level1 li {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    margin-top: 20px;
    list-style-type: none;
}
nav.sidebar ul.level1 li a.expandable {
    outline: 0;
    display: block;
    position: relative;
    width: 100%;
    height: 30px;
    color: white;
    text-decoration: none;
    text-align: left;
    padding: 4px 4px 4px 0px;
    font-size: 20px;
}
nav.sidebar ul.level1 li a.expandable:hover {
    color: #bbbbbb;
}
nav.sidebar ul.level1 li a.expandable span.expanded-element {
    display: none;
    font-size: 11px;
    position: relative;
    bottom: 5px;
}
nav.sidebar ul.level1 li.active {
    margin-left: -4px;
}
nav.sidebar ul.level1 li.active a.expandable {
    background: none repeat scroll 0 0 black;
    border-radius: 4px;
    color: white !important;
    width: 30px;
    padding: 4px;
}
nav.sidebar ul.level1 li.active a.expandable:hover {
    color: white !important;
}
nav.sidebar ul.level1 ul.level2 {
    margin: 20px 6px 20px 30px;
    padding: 0;
    display: none;
}
nav.sidebar ul.level1 ul.level2 li {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    margin-top: 10px;
    padding-bottom: 10px;
    list-style-type: none;
    border-bottom: solid white 1px;
}
nav.sidebar ul.level1 ul.level2 li:last-child {
    border-bottom: none;
}
nav.sidebar ul.level1 ul.level2 li a {
    text-decoration: none;
    outline: 0;
    color: white;
    text-decoration: none;
    font-size: 11px;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<div class="row" style="height:60px; margin-bottom:10px;">
 <div class="well">
  Header area
 </div>
</div>

<div class="row">
 <nav class="sidebar sidebar-menu-collapsed">
  <a href="#" id="justify-icon" style="color: rgb(255, 255, 255);">
   <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-align-justify"></span>
  </a>
  <ul class="level1">
            <li class="active">
    <a class="expandable" href="#" title="Dashboard" style="padding: 4px; width: 100%;">
     <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-home collapsed-element"></span>
     <span class="expanded-element" style="display: none;">Dashboard</span>
    </a>
            </li>
            <li>
    <a class="expandable" href="#" title="APIs" style="padding: 1px 4px 4px 0px;">
     <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-thumbs-up collapsed-element"></span>
     <span class="expanded-element" style="display: none;">Thumbs Up</span>
    </a>
            </li>
            <li>
    <a class="expandable" href="#" title="Settings" style="padding: 1px 4px 4px 0px;">
     <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-picture collapsed-element"></span>
     <span class="expanded-element" style="display: none;">Picture</span>
    </a>
            </li>
        </ul> 
  <a href="#" id="logout-icon" title="Logout">
   <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-off"></span>
  </a>
    </nav>
 <div class="col-md-8">
  <div class="row">
   <div class="col-md-12">
    <div class="well">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.</div>
   </div>
  </div>
  <div class="row">
   <div class="col-md-12">
    <div class="well">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.</div>
   </div>
  </div>
 </div>
</div>
<style>
  html, body { margin: 0; min-height: 100%; min-width: 100%; padding: 0; }
  .row { margin: 0; width: 100%; }
  .row .row { width: auto; }
  .row nav { position: relative; }
  .row nav, .row nav ~ div { display: table-cell; }
</style>
```

Comment: It works in the windowed mode but when you open to full page the main information slides down below it. But yes, it is the right function in the window mode.